# Panorama in BB10

Tags: blackberry, qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I used this code to start the camera on BB10.

```
Container {
// ...

onCreationCompleted: {
var cameraUnit = getCameraUnit(qmlCameraObj.supportedCameras);

if (cameraUnit != null) {
    qmlCameraObj.open(cameraUnit);

    // ...
}

// ...
}
```

Is there anyway to capture 360 degree image or panorama image in BB10?

Answer (score 0):

Actually currently BlackBerry Cascades do not support any APIs for capture 360 degree or panorama image...  (until 10.2.1)

10.3 Camera has built in Panorama feature but seems like still no API support in 10.3 Beta SDK.

To achieve your goal, I think you can do the same thing as other Panorama apps (like 360 Panorama in BlackBerry World)... they create a virtual globe and using the Gyro Sensors to capture many images then merge them together...

I don't have any experience on the Panorama merging, but I still hope this answer can help you :)

Thanks

Simon